# get all words from a string into multiple strings c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to take in an input command(ex. set rate 1) and seperate the three words into 2 strings and and integer. When i run this code, I only recieve the first word(set). What am I doing wrong?.

```
void Tool::toolInterface(){
    string input;
    string partInput;
    string partInput1;
    int partInput2;

    //string delimiter = " ";
    cout << "auDiskTool, version 1.0.0. Type ‘help’ to find more about commands\n";
    cout << ">";

    cin >> input;

    int length = input.length();
    char str[length];
    string buf;
    stringstream ss(input);
    vector<string> indInput;

    while(!ss.eof()) {
        ss >> partInput;
        ss >> partInput1;
        ss >> partInput2
    }

    cout << partInput;
    cout << partInput1;
    cout << partInput2;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cin >> input;  will read 1 word and store it in input.
```

If you want to read to multiple input data use same number of variables like below.

http://ideone.com/RSKO3t

Comment: While providing a running example it would still have been nice had you included the code with your question.

Answer (score 1):

cin stops reading when it encounters a space.

try using:

```
getline(cin,input);
```